# TeamCity: dont see Branch Tab in some projects

Tags: teamcity

What the difference in configs ?

Project with Branches Tab:

[image: Project with Branches Tab]

Project without Branches Tab:

[image: Project without Branches Tab]

Comment: We had the same issue, the solution was to Detach the VCS, then re-attach them.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one branch specified in the VCS config, you won't see a Branches tab.

Comment: I have same VCS configs for both Projects

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity doesn't show branches in a project in case it knows nothing about them, i.e. there are no builds/changes in the project since project have been created. So if there is an old project with builds, newly created one has no knowledge regarding those builds. Try running a build in a branch, it should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add branch specification `*` in VCS Root settings and test connection to force Team City to fetch information about branches from git repository.